# Can the .NET 4 Client Profile be deployed via ClickOnce to non administrators?

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I have deployed [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) applications regularly via [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) that are installed by users that are not local administrators on their machines. Is there a way to also deliver the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4 Client Profile the same way?

From what I have read, I am guessing the answer is no. But I'm also hoping there may be a clever alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  ClickOnce just copies and synchronises files. Obviously the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) [Client Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_3.5_SP1_Client_Profile) install is a lot more involved than that. In addition, you [need to be an administrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656819%28VS.90%29.aspx) to install it. I know I'm not telling you anything you don't already know, just confirming :)

Prerequisites are the pitfall of ClickOnce. Always a pain. What kind of environment are you deploying to? Captive intranet? If so, you might want to ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) what options are available to push the Client Profile to your users.

Comment: Thanks whatknott - yes, captive intranet is the scenario. But avoiding having to engage a different group capable of pushing was the goal :)

Comment: I hear you - always much better when you can handle it yourself.  If you find a work around, please come back and keep us updated.